# Tomcat server reaching a websocket limit of 2000 connections

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, server

I currently have a web app built in Java 8 on Tomcat 9. This app uses Websockets through javax.websockets + ServerEndpoint and is connected to with a Javascript client.

**When I stress test this server, if the number of open Websockets hits 2000 - the server will stop processing requests until some Websocket connections close and bring the count below 2000.** The server isn't hitting memory, file handle or CPU limits and basically has nothing in its queue for the moment it stops since it handles actual transactions quite quickly. As far as my web app is concerned, its not even receiving the requests while the connections are at 2000.

The server uses the APR native for its HTTP connector and more a less default settings. I have tried adjusting maxConnections and maxThreads, but they seem to have no effect on it. The server is a single EC2 instance on AWS.

I see nothing in the Tomcat documentation outside of these two arguments that could possibly control the maximum sockets. This is the entry for our connector

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    maxThreads="1000" scheme="https"  SSLEnabled="true"
    SSLCertificateFile="conf/cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/nopasskey.pem"
    SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
/>
```

Am I missing something here? Is there other options that control the maximum allowable websockets?

**Note: I just want to clarify, when this limit is reached, users can still connect to the server. However, their connection seems to be put on some sort waiting queue to be processed, rather than just being handed off to the web app at 2000 connections. This makes it so users can still connect, but they wont get a response till their connection is given to the web app.**

Comment: What is MaxClients set to on your apache frontend (you mentioned APR)? Does the problem occur when you bypass the apache frontend and hit tomcat directly?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but as far as I know this is *just* apache tomcat, not divisible parts. I see nothing for setting maxClients in Apache Tomcat. 

The APR is just the mechanism chosen for the connection handler in Tomcat. I tried NIO as well, but this didn't change the behaviour.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are probably confusing APR and AJP

Comment: @RamziC. Did you try `maxConnections = -1` ? As the doc mentions _If set to a value of -1, the maxConnections feature is disabled and connections are not counted._

Comment: @EugèneAdell Yes, the server still gets caught at 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely over looked it, but I had an entry redirecting to the APR connector. This redirect wasn't actually working as the **redirectPort** argument is only valid for redirection on specific triggers.

> If this Connector is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is
>   received for which a matching  requires SSL
>   transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the
>   port number specified here.

After setting the APR connector as the main connector and not redirecting it, my configuration options began working as intended. Previously, it was using the HTTP/1.0 connector (aka NIO).